# Properly annotate a HOC in react with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, higher-order-components

I'm having difficulties properly annotating the following HOC. I don't know what to put for the return types of the functions and I don't know how to annotate the props. I'm always getting errors.

```
const withAuthentication = <Props extends object>(
  Component: React.ComponentType<Props>
) => {
  const WithAuthentication = (props: Any) => {
    const { firebase } = props

    return (
      <AuthUserContext.Provider value={authenticated}>
        <Component {...(props as Props)} />
      </AuthUserContext.Provider>
    )
  }

  return withFirebase(WithAuthentication)
}
```

Does anybody know how to fix this is? Help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: could you please add the errors as well

Answer (score 1):

The correct way of specifying the return type of anonymous function expression in typescript is demonstrated like follows. The type specification comes after the argument declaration

```js
const withAuthentication = (
    Component: React.ComponentType<Props>
) : React.Component<Props> => {
    const WithAuthentication = (props: any) => {
        const { firebase } = props;

        return (
            <AuthUserContext.Provider value={authenticated}>
                <Component {...(props as Props)} />
            </AuthUserContext.Provider>
        );
    };

    return withFirebase(WithAuthentication);
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! It seems I'm getting an error in my other HOC when I type it like that (on the return withFirebase(WithAuthentication)): 
```Type 'typeof WithFirebase' is missing the following properties from type 'Component<Props, {}, any>': context, setState, forceUpdate, render, and 3 more.ts(2740)```

Not sure what it means though

Comment: I assumed that `withFirebase` is also a react component. try replacing `: React.Component<Props>` with whatever type `withFirebase` is returning